# K means clustering

Tags: k-means, outliers

While using K-means clustering, I have removed the top 5 and bottom 5 percentile values of independent variables, because of which I lose out on few data points.
Now after I use K-means clustering, I get clusters for each data points. How do I get clusters for the data points which were earlier removed because of being an outlier

Answer (score 0):

Well just perform the entire K-means with outlier treatment. Once the algorithm is complete (outliers removed at every iteration), you could assign them back to the closest clusters. This way, the cluster mean doesn't change, but outliers get a suitable label.

Comment: Hi, please tell me how to assign them back to clusters since I have to calculate the distance using multiple variables. Also, should I calculate the distance from the normalized values or the normal one